# Are there HTTP/2 specific attacks different from request smuggling?

Tags: attacks, web, research, http2, request-smuggling

I'm researching information about HTTP/2 from a cybersecurity point of view for an article, and i wanted to include a section about attacks exclusive to HTTP/2 or were this protocol have a key role.

I already got information about request smuggling in HTTP/2 but I have difficulty to find other types of attack related to this protocol. Are there other attacks related to HTTP/2 protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2019, [a number of HTTP/2 vulnerabilities were discovered](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/605641/), that were affecting a number of HTTP/2 servers and clients.

These vulnerabilities are specific to HTTP/2 and are not present in HTTP/1.1, and should be a good starting point as examples of attacks for the HTTP/2 protocol.